# How can I recover files off this disk that won't mount?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

I have an HFS+ disk that will not mount.  I've tried it in multiple enclosures, and the problem is the disk itself.  Disk Utility says it cannot repair, and so does DiskWarrior.  With `fsck` I get this weird output.

```
$ sudo fsck_hfs /dev/disk4
** /dev/rdisk4 (NO WRITE)
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-285).
volumeType is 0
0000:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
01b0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00fe       |................|
01c0:  ffff eefe ffff 0100 0000 af6d 7074 0000       |...........mpt..|
01d0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
01f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 55aa       |..............U.|
```

Here is some output from syslog:

```
9/29/16 08:11:58.747 diskarbitrationd[67]: unable to repair /dev/disk4s2 (status code 0x00000008).
9/29/16 08:11:58.752 diskarbitrationd[67]: unable to mount /dev/disk4s2 (status code 0x00000001).
```

Answer (score 1):

Disk4 is the whole disk device and **no** slice with an (HFS) file system. The output is the content of block0 omitting most lines containing only zeros. Block zero often is equivalent to the MBR/pMBR of a disk. Block0 doesn't contain a file system!

[image]

To verify/repair a file system, you have to choose a particular partition and the volume has to be mounted. The common external disk has two partitions: the EFI and the main volume - so try:

```
sudo fsck_hfs -f /dev/disk4s2
```

If the external disk has more than one visible volume, enter `diskutil list` and choose the appropriate partition (e.g disk4s3 or disk4s4).

---

If fsck_hfs fails to mount and/or repair the disk, try a data recovery tool like Data Rescue, R-Studio, Disk Drill etc.

If they also fail contact a professional data recovery specialist like Kroll Ontrack.